# Help me understand division in modular arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

From Wikipedia:

**In mathematics, modular arithmetic is a system of arithmetic for integers, where numbers "wrap around" upon reaching a certain value**

So the point of modular arithmetic is to do our normal arithmetic operations wrap around after reaching a certain value.

From what I read [https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch03.html](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Emrh/330tutor/ch03.html) about modular arithmetic operations, they are just normal operations, same as how we use in normal arithmetic.

Consider  modulo n:

- modulo addition is defined (a+b)mod n
- modulo subtraction is defined as (a-b) mod n
- modulo multiplication is defined as (a*b) mod n
- **modulo division is defined as (a/b) mod n**

After defining above arithmetic operations  *we just happened to have found out that this is true*, (a+b)mod n =(a mod n + b mod n) mod n which is similar with multiplication and subtraction.

That doesn't mean that modular addition is (a mod n + b mod n) or does it? (correct me if I am wrong).

now consider modular division as it is defined as  (a/b) mod n

**ex: consider a=48,b=8,n=4 (here b is multiple of n)**

Now from what i understand
This is perfectly fine **(48/8)mod 8=6**  right ! but as it says in above
so when we **modular division is not valid (a/b) modulo n when b is multiple of n.**

But can't we just say  (a/b) modulo n != (a mod n)/( b mod n) and move on.

So everything boils down to following questions.

**1.Does while doing modular arithmetic every number 'p' that is ever going to used in arithmetic operation should be in  [0,n) so modular arithmetic is ((a mod n + b mod n) mod n)**

**2.It doesn't matter what numbers you are using, at the end, value should be 0<= V< n
so modular arithmetic is (some long cumbersome arithmetic expressions) mod n**

Explain where I am getting this wrong, this is bothering me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try my best to answer concisely:

1. It is not a condition for $a,b$ to be in $[0,n)$ but since every integer is equivalent to one, it makes sense to use numbers in this range
2. When I studied this, I liked to think that rather than division of $a$ by $b$, we multiply by the inverse of $b$. If $a|n$ there is no inverse (it is 'like' dividing by zero in a naïve sense)

To find the inverse of $b\mod{c}$ there is the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: I didn't actually get what you mean by _It is not a condition for a,b to be in [o,n) but since every integer is equivalent to one, it makes sense to use numbers in this range_

Comment: Ok, sorry it wasn't clear! Modular arithmetic splits up integers into classes. For example, $4 \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$ so $4$ and $1$ are in the same class mod $3$. If you wanted to add $4$ and $5$ them then you don't *have* to use $1+2 (\mod 3)$ - in fact you can use any integers in the same class as $1$ and $2$, but yes it does make sense to use the numbers in the range $[0,n)$ as they are the 'canonical' representation of the different equivalence classes

Comment: so in any operation if a number is replaced by any number that is in it's corresponding equivalence class result should be same,is that it. lets just suppose  modulo 3 then {0,3,6,9} all mean same in modular arithmetic when we are in modulo 3 system

Comment: Yes, that's right! Apologies for the slow response

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple definition of the $\pmod n$ operator, in that if we have $x\equiv a\pmod n$, then we may write $x=a+kn$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

We reduce $a$ to a value in $[0,n)$ and fix $k$ accordingly.

So:

$$(a+b) \pmod n = (a+b) + kn$$

for some $k$.

And:

$$a \pmod n + b \pmod n = a+k_an + b+k_bn = (a+b) + (k_a+k_b)n = (a+b) + kn$$

So these two are the same.

With division, the two resulting formula are not the same:

$$\frac ab \pmod n = \frac ab + kn$$

$$\frac{a \pmod n}{b \pmod n} = \frac{a + k_an}{b + k_bn}$$